# setting hashcode and equals to create a set with unique object

Tags: java, hash-code-uniqueness

I would create a `Set` exactly `HashSet` to contains only `char`.for example `a,b,c,d,e,f,g...`
but these `char`s are not represented by the primitive type but I have an object

```
public FirstChar{

  private char c;

  public FirstChar(char c){

    this.c = c;

  }
}
```

Now i want to add the object `FirstChar` into a set but to avoid repeated elements I have to implement `HashCode()` and `equals()`

I know how to implement `equals` but how can i implement `hashcode` in the way I could have only one element in the set?

NB. Please don't say me to use Eclipse

Comment: do you want to have at most one of each 'a', 'b', 'c', etc, or only one char in entire set?

Comment: yes.only one letter in the entire set

Comment: @Mazzy: So you want *every* instance of `FirstChar` to be equal to every other instance? This sounds very odd. Perhaps you could explain your use case in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: I've just read your comment that you only want one letter in the entire set - which sounds like a *very* odd requirement, but it's basically fulfilled by something like:

```
public final class FirstChar {

  private final char c;

  public FirstChar(char c) {
    this.c = c;
  }

  @Override public int hashCode() {
      return 0;
  }

  @Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
      return other instanceof FirstChar;
  }
}
```

In other words, every instance of `FirstChar` is deemed equal to every other instance, and they all have the same hash code. As I say, this is really strange... is it *definitely* what you want?

---

**Original answer**

Implementing `hashCode()` for a value which only logically has a single character is easy:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return c; // Use implicit conversion to int
}
```

Check against the contract of `Object.hashCode` and you'll find this works fine - assuming your `equals` method basically just compares values of `c`. (It's not clear what you meant when you wrote "in the way I could have only one element in the set" - I assume you mean only one element per distinct character.)

However, I'm confused as to what value your `FirstChar` class provides over just using `java.lang.Character`. Is there any reason you can't just use a `Set<Character>`?

Comment: Jon Skeet occasionally wins so many badges that the notifications hide his entire browser. He continues answering questions unhindered.

Comment: the reason I don't use wrapper Character is because every letter has to contain a collection of object Person who their surname starts with that letter

Comment: @Mazzy: That sounds like a very odd requirement - any reason you're not using a `Map<Character, List<Person>>` or something similar (e.g. a `Multimap` from Guava)?

Comment: the reason is because I want a collection of element that are not repeated but every of this elements have to contain a list so every element has to be an object to contain a collection

Comment: @JonSkeet but a Map has two fields.the key and the value. Now I need only one field.in the collection we could have more person with the same first letter of surname so Map can't help me

Answer (score 1):

In any case, from what I can tell, the `hashCode` method in the `Character` class simply returns the `char` as an `int`.

In your specific case, if you want the set to only contain the first `FirstChar` added to it, you can make all `FirstChar`s equal to each other:

```
class FirstChar{
    private char c;
    public FirstChar(char c){
        this.c=c;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return String.valueOf(c);
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        return o instanceof FirstChar;
    }
    public int hashCode(){        
        return 42;
    }
}
```

But unless you have a very good reason, this doesn't sound like a good idea.